# CSS Font Icons font-family being ignored

Tags: css, font-face

I have a font which replaces the following characters with icons:

> ' ( * + $ % # ) "

I have defined the following CSS:

```
/* Define the fonts for use */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'assets';
    src: url('AAHS_ASSETS.eot');
    src: url('AAHS_ASSETS.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('AAHS_ASSETS.TTF') format('truetype');
}

/* ASSETS */
[class^="icon-aahs-assets-"],
[class*=" icon-aahs-assets-"] {
  font-family: "assets";
}

.icon-aahs-assets-asset:before { content: "$"; }
```

When I add the following icon in html, it displays as a $

```
<i class="icon-aahs-assets-asset"></i>
```

I have checked the network response and the font is being downloaded by the browser (testing in Chrome).

How do I make sure it displays the icon?

Comment: Where did you get the icon fonts from? In most cases, sites recommend that you either have `data-icon` attributes for each element or you have separate classes for each icon.

Comment: Assuming that you have tested that your selectors work (by using an easily observable setting in the rule), the problem would appear to be in the font. What do we know about the font? If you install it and view text using it, does it really show some special characters when text contains ' ( * + $ % # ) "?

Comment: The font does show special characters when those chars are displayed. However, I recreated the font using http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator and used the CSS which is generated and it now works. Couldn't see any major differences, so maybe it was in the encoding of the font file.

Answer (score 0):

Try set characters in unicode. E.g.

$ - `\0024`

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the font working, so I used this tool to generate the CSS and fonts:

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

I couldn't see any major differences between the CSS, so maybe it was in the conversion of the font file.